# instant upload of camera pictures into Google picasaweb without Google+ app?

Tags: photos, picasa

Is there any option to have instant upload of camera pictures into Google picasaweb without the Google+ app? I have an HTC Chacha 2.3.5 which runs short of memory (even when moving apps to SD), and I can't be bothered of having Google+ installed, but would like to keep the instant upload of camera pictures into Picasa. Right now the Camera app (HTC Version 2.6.2119262927.162876) in the phone can only do instant upload into Flickr or Facebook, but I would rather prefer have them in Picasa. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean instant and automatic, that is, photo is uploaded as soon as you take picture?

Comment: Yes, I mean instant and automatic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an app for that.

[PhotoSync (Sync to Picasa)](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.zehai.photosync) automatically syncs local folder to Picasaweb, so you can select your camera folder. It's free and not so huge as G+ app. You can set your local folder and Picasa folder and sync them on eg. hourly basis.

Comment: I agree with Tschareck and with @louielouie (below) - a separate app is required, you cannot modify the behavior of HTC's software AFAIK. The choice, then, would be which app suits your needs while taking up the least space.

Answer (score 1):

I would bite the bullet and install the Google+ app.

In addition to Instant Upload, the Google+ app will give you unlimited storage of the photos that are uploaded via Instant Upload:

> All photos uploaded in Google+ will be automatically resized to 2048 pixels (on their longest edge) and won't count towards your free storage quota.

Source: http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1224181

I don't think you have to use Google+ other than register online and install the app for this to happen, so there's really not much effort on your part needed to get the benefits of Instant Upload.

You can also manually "share" photos from the Gallery app to Picasa, but that's more tedious.